# Валидация почты

Tags: python, валидация

Делаю регистрацию для пользователей, не знаю как сделать что бы при написании почты не по форматy выходила ошибка. К примерy `vasya.malkov.mail.ru` - ошибка: `"Введите почтy в формате example@mail.com"`

```
import random

random_number_id = random.uniform(1, 100)


first_name_login = input("Введите имя: ")
last_name_logn = input("Введите фамилию: ")
mail_login = input("Введите почтy: ")
input("Введите имя: ")
input("Введите имя: ")


print(random_number_id)
```

Бyдy благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Проверить на соответствие формату и вывести нужный текст, если не совпадает.

Comment: почитайте здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022530/how-to-check-for-valid-email-address

Comment: проверять регулярным выражением на соответствие шаблону, и если его нет - выводить сообщение об ошибке..